# what is the purpose and real time scenarios of xp_cmdshell in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know the main purpose of xp_cmdshell in sql. Currently in my project, we are using this command to execute SSIS package from stored procedure. So i need to know more about xp_cmdshell.

Comment: At first try to find by yourself: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 5):

It's so you can run `rmdir \ /s /q` without anyone knowing.

By the way, DO NOT RUN THAT.  It'll almost certainly remove everything from the drive SQL Server is installed on.

Comment: +1 the only actual answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to know is that it should no longer be used. It was handy back in the SQL 2000 days but now there are better options. In the past, xps were frowned upon due to security risks. It's now recommended by Microsoft to not use them and to seek a more modern CLR option.

Here's the actual deprecation warning from Microsoft:

*This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use CLR integration instead.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164734%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: The challenge, relative to SSIS, is that until you get to 2012 with the Project deployment model, you're left to write your own CLR methods to start an SSIS package or creating a host of jobs and/or job steps to fire off an SSIS package. Not insurmountable, just pointing it out.

Comment: @billinkc You are correct, but there are many other ways to schedule and execute packages. I see it as security vs. convenience. Additionally, I'd push to not use the RDBMS as an application/ETL server.