# Should NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICES be assigned sysadmin

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a mini web app that can do some bcp export to a remote server. Now everything works fine except that in order to get xp_cmdshell to work, I assigned sysadmin to NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICES. 
I wonder whether it's good practice to do that?

I know there is other way to avoid assigning sysadmin to get xp_cmdshell to work, such as the link below: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890775
but I don't know whether this works on NT AUTHORITY/NETWORK SERVICES?

Thanks for any advice!

Bcp code referred can be found at 
[BCP Export Login Failed for User NT Authority/Anonymous Logon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849281/bcp-export-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

Comment: The right way to do this is to make a dedicated account for this that runs the code. otherwise you end up granting sa to all automatic execute code. (i hope i dont have to explain why that would be bad!)

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25454212/1595565 about why `xp_cmdshell` is bad, bad.